# Firebase update node instead of adding new one

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is currently how my firebase database looks.

[image]

I am trying to perform an update where when I click the `like` button, the user will appear in `liked` attribute (the second one above). currently it is just hardcoded but the code is not doing quite what i want it to do.

```
 function liked(name, useruid, user_liked){
      var postData = {
        name: name,
        useruid: useruid,
        user_liked: user_liked
      };

      var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

      var updates = {};
      updates['/users/' + name + '/' + '/liked/' + user_liked] = postData;
      return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
    }
```

I call this function with `liked(current_user_name, user_array[i].useruid, 'Hannah')`

I would like then the `liked: "liked` attribute to read `liked: "liked", "Hannah"`
However instead it does the following below:

[image]

It has added in information I do not want and instead of adding to the array it has transformed it. it must be a tiny change but i cant quite see it

exported json before update:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "rich" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "liked" : "liked",
      "name" : "rich",
      "not_liked" : "liked",
      "username" : "rich@rich.com",
      "useruid" : "5xO85K2EBOS6Itj7lKoGafm19i02"
    }
  }
}
```

exported json after update:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "rich" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "liked" : {
        "Hannah" : {
          "name" : "rich",
          "user_liked" : "Hannah",
          "useruid" : "5xO85K2EBOS6Itj7lKoGafm19i02"
        }
      },
      "name" : "rich",
      "not_liked" : "liked",
      "username" : "rich@rich.com",
      "useruid" : "5xO85K2EBOS6Itj7lKoGafm19i02"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. When you do this change, show the JSON as you have it before you run the update and the JSON as you want it to be **after** the update.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see edited code

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any idea now?